# how to send specific keys in the keyboard?

Tags: c#

I want to send (Tab) key to the active form (as if I pressed Tab key)

I am using `SendKeys.Send(Keys.Tab.ToString());`

It work fine for other string

For example : `SendKeys.Send("my string");`
but it does not work for Tab key

can you help me?

Comment: `my string` is not a valid key to send.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this site, you need to use a code: `{TAB}`

```
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx